# Inquiry answerer

Tags: code-golf, string

- Original: https://james-iry.blogspot.co.at/2009/05/brief-incomplete-and-mostly-wrong.html

  > Alain Colmerauer designed the logic programming language Prolog. His goal was to create a programming language that is as intelligent as a two-year-old child. In order to prove that he had succeeded in his goal, he presented a Prolog program that answers "No" resourcefully for all inquiries. 
  >   Ask me anything!
  >   ?-
- (Of course he didn't.) Your task is to create a program that is more intelligent than Alain Colmerauer's program. This does not have to be in Prolog.

### Specifics

- If input ends with `?` and has at least one `,`, return text from the last `,` until before the last `?`.
- Else, if input ends with `?` return `No`.
- Else, return `Yes`.

### Rules

- No standard loopholes.
- Input/output will be taken via our standard input/output methods.
- Your program has to take at least 1 inquiry.
- You should output the processed inquiry.
- The `Yes` and `No`'s are case-sensitive in the examples.
- You are guaranteed that if the input includes a `?`, the input will only have one `?` and it will always be the last character.
- The input will always be a phrase/sentence. This phrase/sentence will never only contain the characters `,` and `?`, e.g. `,`, `?`, and `,?` are not valid inputs. (Although submissions might implement it anyway, since the phrase/sentence is an empty string in these cases.)
- In addition, the input will never end with `,?`.
- If there is whitespace immediately after the last `,` or immediately before the `?`, they should be included in the output.

### Examples

```
Hmm. -> Yes
Alright, -> Yes
Ask me anything! -> Yes
Ask me a question, please! -> Yes
Are you okay? -> No
No? -> No
Hey,does this program work? -> does this program work

Quotes in the following test cases should not be outputted.
They are used as a delimiter here.

Okay, so this does work ? -> " so this does work "
Please, add, a, test, case, containing, multiple, commas? -> " commas"
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: Are we guaranteed that if the input includes a `?`, there will only be one and it will always be the last character?

Comment: Please add a test case containing multiple commas.

Comment: Can the input be `?`, `,`, or `,?`

Comment: Accepting an answer early may discourage other users from posting new answers, because it kind of looks like the challenge is done.

Comment: If there is a space immediately after the last `,` or immediately before the `?`, should they be included in the output or trimmed off?

Comment: Test cases: `Is this thing on? Testing, testing.`, `Is this thing on? Testing, testing?`, and `Is this thing on? Testing testing?` (If I've read the challenge correctly the oututs should be `Yes`, `testing`, and `No` respectively).

Comment: ```You are guaranteed that if the input includes a ?, the input will only have one ? and it will always be the last character.``` Therefore these test cases are unneccecary.

Comment: Is `ends with ,?` a valid input?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>20</s> 19 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
'?åi',¡”€–”0ǝθ¨ë”…Ü
```

-1 byte thanks to *@Grimy*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f3f7w0kx1nUMLHzXMfdS05lHDZCDD4PjcczsOrTi8GiTYsOzwnP//PVIrdVLyU4sVSjIyixUKivLTixJzFcrzi7LtAQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##PY0xCsIwGIX3nuLXxSWINwhuncQrxDZoqMlfm1QJKBQHZ9HVDg6KoAdwbgY3D9GLxOjg8r@f7/HeQ80mgvv10ro97UK7O0CX@h51F9Ejzbmt6nb7aKtjeAav@v1sbu7@hdXVnYL6DfGxlP1oqDOQHJiyZibUtPMHsCi5NgIVgXzOmebBKjhYLAEzZmk0QhrF3JIUuYYQ1pAXOC2YhBUWGY3GvxQBlqbhEDChjkDyYwkqw4QKgwRkOTciTHyplEzTDw).

**Explanation:**

```python
'?åi          '# If the (implicit) input contains a "?":
    ',¡       '#  Split the (implicit) input on ","
       ”€–”    #  Push dictionary string "Not"
           0ǝ  #  Insert it at the first position (index 0) in the list
       θ       #  Then get the last item of the list
        ¨      #  And remove the last character
               #  (either the "?" of the original input; or the "t" in "Not")
      ë        # Else:
       ”…Ü     #  Push dictionary string "Yes"
               # (after which the top of the stack is output implicitly as result)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `”€–”` is `"Not"` and `”…Ü` is `"Yes"`.

Comment: [20](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVnl4gr2SwqO2SQpK9v/V7Q@3Htqfqa5zaOGjhrmPmtY8apgMZBgcn3tux6EVh1eDBBuWHZ4DpP/X6vz3yM3V43IszlbITVVIzKssycjMS1eECygUlqYWl2Tm5@koFOSkJhanAqWKUhUq80sV8rMTK@25/PLtuTxSK3VS8lOLFYCaixUKivLTixJzFcrzi7LtAQ "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Comment: @Grimy Oh, smart thinking. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 62 bytes

```python
lambda s:['Yes',*s[:-1].split(','),'No'][~(','in s)*('?'in s)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc7BCsIwDAbgu08R8ZBuVEG8DXR487S7zB0qq1q2NrWZSC@@@pyIelFvSf6PJD52J3KL/rDc9a2y@1oBZyVuNaNMucym82rGvjWdQImJxIKwKm@PxjjgJBWYP6uq98G4ThwEbqydYZLAZLqCYdHoHay5AatBueGoccfxXwTni@bOkJPgW61Y/@BBQ6QLUKNi/hIFfUBBX8cbHWVNmmF4hcEHOgZl4UqhefPvcX8H)

The expression `~(','in s)*('?'in s)` evaluates to `0` (i.e. `'Yes'`) if the string does not contain a `'?'`, else `-1` (i.e. `'No'`) if the string does not contain a `','`, and otherwise `-2` (i.e. the last comma-separated section of the string excluding the last character).

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>53</s>  52 bytes

```javascript
s=>(m=s.match(/(,?)([^,]*)\?/))?m[1]?m[2]:'No':'Yes'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ndJBa4MwFADge3/FmxfjyJTt2GJlh0HZwQ52Gp2FoNE6jc/lxQ1/vUvsZYNC1@YQyEveR/JePsSXoFzXvbnrsJBTGU8Ur5mKKVTC5AcWMZ4EbLfn2W3wnkRBkKjdfWanh2zpp@gv/TdJ/rTaLQC8jVKhx@GaEUXgWclzzCM1oCSIbjSHuqtuLiBPMfA5SDI1dhz6VgqS58E/jJYw4gDYiDG57HWOSXFWUkyurMxvZSNHXqAksIUh6DVWWij4Rt2c1Z1yOnWWt/Z1HAiP2/NBtwf/uLWTT2TO7MtccA6iKOzEwdhOcMjnWI6dEXVnO8xBDa2pbXdcVClBiXdkjytvkS3CEvWTsD@SIF67XMJWhi1W7Pl1m4ZktIXqcmQlo8CO1fQD)

#### Commented

```javascript
s =>                  // s = input string
  ( m = s.match(      // m is the result of matching in s:
  //     +------------>    an optional comma
  //     |     +------>    followed by a string containing no comma
  //     |     |   +-->    followed by a question mark
  //   <--><-----><>     
      /(,?)([^,]*)\?/
  )) ?                // if m is not null:
    m[1] ?            //   if the comma exists:
      m[2]            //     output the string following it
    :                 //   else:
      'No'            //     output 'No'
  :                   // else:
    'Yes'             //   output 'Yes'
```

Comment: Welp, was looking for a JS solution, ended up with something double this size.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>23</s> 22 bytes

```
¿№θ?¿№θ,⁻⊟⪪θ,¦?¦No¦Yes
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vcs9DsIwDAXgnVNYmVLJnIChAzMoEhNjlAaw5PxQJ71@CKUIsVh633t2Dzu7ZLk1uoE@phqLfiKoUQ0D/BO@yczU44liFW1S1pfM9Ku3xwN4Fr9t1Tmpr@SPXL10as2wt@IR7DT1g1C8FAS3mkuxWIoU7wihcqHMq4ZgZdy1/cIv) Link is to verbose version of code. Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @KevinCruijssen. Explanation:

```
¿№θ?
```

Does the string contain any `?`s?

```
¿№θ,
```

Does it contain any `,`s?

```
⊟⪪θ,
```

Split the string on `,`s and take the last.

```
⁻...?
```

Delete the `?` and output the result.

```
No
```

If there are no `,`s then output `No`.

```
Yes
```

If there are no `?`s then output `Yes`.

Comment: -1 changing `Print(Join(Split(Pop(Split(q, ",")), "?"), w)` to `Print(Minus(Pop(Split(q, ",")), "?");`

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks, I'd forgotten that `Minus` did that. Besides, I was feeling pleased with myself for saving two separators.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-plF/,|\?/`, 25 bytes

```perl
$_=/\?$/?/,/?pop@F:No:Yes
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY6xagMxEER7fcUGXG6iKo0hbNwYV07agCEI33IWJ2llrY5wkG@PortAmi3ezOxM5hKeW9t9vtgL7SxZtJQlvx73Z9l/sLZ2ivHJHELx462iOegEkcGlpd58Gh/@Adxn1uolIeTATrlLhWGRGWRyC5mzkDnxgoOwQg8r5CJjcRG@pExk3roLQeVP21yrAGTet38Ibhj6Qai9COG6sauk6nzqUxDiHKrv5SuN0Sn9SF4XaXvM4Wjx@0L2Fw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 25 bytes

```
?qeQ\??}\,QPecQ\,"No""Yes
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcg7CsAgDADQq0jm3MEbFB0LLkFDK/grSYcOPbstLm9449FzTnuxD9a@Ab3j6APC1gF2ljnBFSZhNJTSDxplUTRxXexNKbfcDjT1LppHWVsriYUP)

```
?q                          # if       ==
  eQ\?                      #    Q[-1]    "?":
      ?}                    #   if     in   
        \,Q                 #      ","    Q:
             cQ\,           #     return split(Q, ",")
            e               #                         [-1] (last element)
           P                #                             [:-1] (remove the trailing ?)
                 "No"       #   else: return "No"
                     "Yes"  # else: return "Yes" (last " implicit)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>32</s> 28 bytes

```
^'?K`Yes
.+,(.*)\?
$1
'?K`No
```

-4 bytes with tips from *@Neil*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##PY3NCsIwEITveYoVFP9CoU8QPFkQildBpEu71NAmW5MUydPHtAcvc/iGb8ZR0BbLtDtcm/Taq1vzIC@KszwUp@NTiW0pFlhzSpUxhbj4AQwB2hje2vabP4DPTD5othKmkdBTrhxB5Bl4wKhEzUpUFGXH5CHLHibHvUMDX3aDEvfVkoBdl0NCyHMS2pW1bANqmw8lmHkMOl8s1Bj06gc)

**Explanation:**

```python
   K`       # Replace any (implicit) input, which does
^           # NOT
 '?        '# contain a "?"
     Yes    # with "Yes"

.+          # Match 1 or more characters
  ,         # followed by a comma
    .*      # followed by zero or more characters,
   (  )     # (captured in capture group 1)
       \?   # followed by a (trailing) "?"
$1          # And replace it with just the match of capture group 1,
            # (so everything between the last comma and trailing question mark)

  K`        # Replace any remaining string, which does
'?         '# contain a "?"
    No      # with "No"

            # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: Did you know that Retina 1's `K` stage has a built-in conditional? I didn't. It could probably save you a few bytes.

Comment: @Neil I'm not sure how to chain the `K` and conditional `&` to be completely honest. I know how to use `K` with a regex to match [like this](https://tio.run/##PY1BCoMwFET3OcUvWLA1KJ4gdFWhIN2W2mLQjw2afJtESk5vUxfdzOI9ZsaiV0aW6z49t2uRZ/eneCTFpb2hY3nG0/x4aARLShZdI6KoaV0rrXN2ciNoBGmCfykz7P4A3gs6r8hwmCeUDqOyCIEWoFEGwWoSrMLAe0IHsexgtjRYqeFDdhTsurU4yL6PwcHHOQ7dxjoyXioTDznoZfIqXvyo1tKJLw), but how do I combine it with the conditional to mimic a ternary if-else for the `Yes`/`No`?

Comment: You don't need `&`, which is what surprised me, and you can just match on a string, or better still, a character, since you know that any `?` must be at the end.

Comment: @Neil So, [like this?](https://tio.run/##PY3BCsIwEETv@YoVFKqGln5B8GRBKF6FIl3aRUObbE1SJF9fYwUvc3jDm3EUtMVy2WXndrkXjSou7Y28yI8yyw/7RoltKX645mWpjMnFyQ9gCNDG8NT2sfkDeM3kg2YrYRoJPaXKEUSegQeMStSsREVR9kwekuxhcvxwaODNblDiuloSsO9TSAhpTkK3so5tQG3ToQQzj0Gniy81Br36AA) Which is also 32 bytes apparently.

Comment: Not quite; you're still matching on a regex, but you're allowed a string or character instead.

Comment: @Neil Ah, I had no idea it was possible to use characters in Retina like that. I'm not sure if I have [the intended solution](https://tio.run/##PY3NCsIwEITveYoVFP9CoU8QPFkQildBpEu71NAmW5MUydPHtAcvc/iGb8ZR0BbLtDtcm/Taq1vzIC@KszwUp@NTiW0pFlhzSpUxhbj4AQwB2hje2vabP4DPTD5othKmkdBTrhxB5Bl4wKhEzUpUFGXH5CHLHibHvUMDX3aDEvfVkoBdl0NCyHMS2pW1bANqmw8lmHkMOl8s1Bj06gc) now, but it's down -4 to 28.

Comment: I think I had 28. (I might have had the `^` in a different place, not that it matters.)

Answer (score 3):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 51 bytes

```
<<<${${${1#*\?}:+Yes}:-${${${${1##*,}%$1}:-No}%\?}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moanx38bGRqUaBA2VtWLsa620I1OLa610IWIgUWUtnVpVFUOgmF9@rSpQSe1/TS6uNAX1/OzESoWSjNQ8dRDPsxjIzixWSFQoLE0tLsnMz7MHizvn5@YmFuso5OXDJfRQJMozSzIwdPmW5pRkFuSkKiRDVSXmpShUppboYKh0zUsphpihAxT4DwA)

A byte can be saved if `ends with,?` and similar are invalid.

Answer (score 3):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ëw‼◘╔╤▬n→ª▒¡Γ╟ï¿
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=89771308c9d1166e1aa6b1ade2c78ba8&i=Hmm.%0AAlright,%0AAsk+me+anything%21%0AAsk+me+a+question,+please%21%0AAre+you+okay%3F%0ANo%3F%0AHey,does+this+program+work%3F%0AOkay,+so+this+does+work+%3F%0APlease,+add,+a,+test,+case,+containing,+multiple,+commas%3F&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 2):

## IBM/Lotus Notes Formula, 79 bytes

```
@If(@Ends(i;"?");@If(@Contains(i;",");@Left(@RightBack(i;",");"?");"No");"Yes")
```

No TIO for Formula so...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>98</s> 87 bytes

*-9 bytes thanks to ElPedro*

```python
x=input();o="Yes"
if"?"==x[-1]:o=x[(x.rfind(",")+1):-1]if x.count(",")else"No"
print(o)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZAxb9wwDIV3/QqWk4RTDATdXBhGtkxJhyxB20Gx6AtzkuhKMmr/@qvOAYpqkIjvPfIRWvb6LunrdRJPMAAiXreB07JWbb7JgK9UUPGMIw7D9uPu/lcv7dVbl2dOXqNFc7o3fRN4hq2bZE31oBQK4ZOgWjI3JObaZivFcZFcoexF0UaTRk8zzPpIND3Cqa3QfQgnjYCnwIlglgxHwQlua3ZlCVxvpOiXvJIxFs5B3lwo2hil/ve3nK5Uz6nL5Pxnj@kVtDPr4OKbd/1h7nKpmReNPxMac32MsVMPIfP5vVr1UC4QCVxqn8Xp/OUfgN8rlcqSLCyBXKEmZYJdVpCL20f1JKN6pN16oQKtucCS5ZxdhD@SL6N6bi4LRT61w3UTYFTfj3kWnPftslBbkIXpYJOk6ji1VSzENVRu4TcaoyvjXw)

This has been solidly beaten by other answers, but I'm trying out golfing in Python a bit more. Advice is appreciated!

Comment: You can use one print to avoid the assignment, then use a lambda since it's now just one statement, then shorten the inline `if` statements to a list indexing instead and then shorten the conditions to use `in`, then throw it all out because it's too close to [an existing answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/192918/76162)

Comment: A couple of golfs without changing your original approach to get it down to 87 [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZAxb9wwDIV3/QqWk4RTDATdXBhGtkxJhyxB20Gx6AtzkuhKMmr/@qvOAYpqkIjvPfIRWvb6LunrdRJPMAAiXreB07JWbb7JgK9UUPGMIw7D9uPu/lcv7dVbl2dOXqNFc7o3fRN4hq2bZE31oBQK4ZOgWjI3JObaZivFcZFcoexF0UaTRk8zzPpIND3Cqa3QfQgnjYCnwIlglgxHwQlua3ZlCVxvpOiXvJIxFs5B3lwo2hil/ve3nK5Uz6nL5Pxnj@kVtDPr4OKbd/1h7nKpmReNPxMac32MsVMPIfP5vVr1UC4QCVxqn8Xp/OUfgN8rlcqSLCyBXKEmZYJdVpCL20f1JKN6pN16oQKtucCS5ZxdhD@SL6N6bi4LRT61w3UTYFTfj3kWnPftslBbkIXpYJOk6ji1VSzENVRu4TcaoyvjXw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: You can replace `if x.count(",")` with `if~x.find(",")`, saving one byte. `str.find` evaluates to `-1` if the string is not found. If you complement this with the unary operator, it results in `0` if and only if the substring is not present. Alternatively, you can replace it with `if","in x ` for 4 bytes fewer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 34 characters

```
*,*\?=@subst{\*,=;$2}
*\?=No
*=Yes
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ echo -n 'Hey,does this program work?' | gema '*,*\?=@subst{\*,=;$2};*\?=No;*=Yes'
does this program work
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/X0tHK8be1qG4NKm4pDpGS8fWWsWolgsk5pfPpWUbmVr8/39ATmpicaqOQmJKCpDQUShJLS7RUUgGiyXn55UkZuZl5qXrKOSW5pRkFuSARXNzE4vtAQ) / [Try all test cases online!](https://tio.run/##lVFNTwIxED3TXzFskAIpYkj0QjbAwQQvYLyZhZiyW3Y3sO3adqME/e047SYICR68dKbvvfl47Zqb7JiIeMe1gP4UrDD2LeZGhB3SiOisKG7pKqSvwlB3n@50nmb2AjJbKARwubdZLtPmNQ7eK@ybK8mg3AnsfqnC0XtVgdry/dgRc@XxuTq/zcSeJUoYwDEGSq1SzQv4UHrrVdcpX7nAvgyMqmkvdBz4uiu4L3r2ezLgSYIH8w/DIPZYrKTluUS3DIpqZ3M05dCi4KZuWueUdAkpdS7tBugX3PQf7gy4OLy/iEM8l5ICfZJlZTG@CINtMXn8LEVsRYLpAs2QjdKQOxGeELQOzdN/RZPVdzBCF6ShfXUYtDog4kxB30l9VYDTBqq0g1QUfGB07BOgxx7rLcfhxFRrYw/LHgtHreE3cdhckV6IP3Wk0A0IafzDzmlo0KpXctnhd@OaxrXBrRpFZ7ow/Eu6WkG7XftyT@KWSpQUxx8)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 58 bytes

```php
<?=$argn[-1]=='?'?substr(strrchr($argn,','),1,-1)?:No:Yes;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY2xqsJAEEX7fMUoQhQmD9KqYbERK3ntQy3WZEhC3J11Z8MjP@@6prCYW5zLneM6F@NeVSvtW3spyltV5SpXMt4l@HU6X3d@PbeYY77BEotyo7Zn3v6R7CLVHcPyape7eDLmJzvIAIZA2yl0vW0XXwDPkST0bBHcg7RQqjzBxCPwoCeVnVllJ5qwYRJIYwHnufXawD/7QWW/8wpBN00KhJDeIdQzq9kG3dskRDDjI/RJ8aHGaFEvdh@vxOL4Bg)

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 78 bytes

```
func[s][r:"Yes"parse s[to","copy t to"?"(r: last split t",")| to"?"(r:"No")]r]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7BasMwEETv@YqpTg2IfoAvprecQumtGB@EvU6FLa2yK1ME/XdHySG40Muy@2bYGaFx@6Sx6w9Ts01rHDrtO2nMF6lJTpSgXWZjzcCpIKPurXmVBovTDE2Lr6zKx9@nZM5sjr30WxIfMyaYUwhv5vA833VGILhY8rePl5d/JFxX0uw5WqSFnNIfkxAKr@DZlXbHz7y/TlTsyKSoIYokfBEX8MMy710fj@8WbhzrsMg11mJ4sIFjdj7WihZhXbKvVe40BKet2W4)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 40 bytes

```perl6
{m/[\,(.*?)]*\?$/??$0.tail||"No"!!"Yes"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY8/a8MwEMV3fYpnYYodVDtTl9CIbJlM19J0ELGcGls6V7IpIkm/uquYlkLpctz97s97N2jXP8wm4K7BI@azKV8OIitWMn9dHWRaSpmui1G1/eXCK@JJwp@159e5IYesb632Oc4MMGVcyjnut7zcxNqrgCb7TNc5u857Y4rYQVxlO9/BaCgbxrfWnpK/HO@T9mNLVmDotfL6d8JpBJpAnQryBitiFf1kex1ETdojnvUYHJ2cMvgg1y0T/7fY0yIhoOo6BoExagscF3YkGx@30aSAmfqxjX5u1Bjll5vf@Rc)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>66</s> <s>63</s> 62 bytes

```python
lambda i:("Yes",("No",i[i.rfind(",")+1:-1])[","in i])["?"in i]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY8/b4MwEMX3fopXT0a4kdIRKUXdMkVZq7SDGww5gX3ENmr49PSgS294@vndnyePc75xeF3aw@cyWP/dWFCl1YdLymh1YmXoQrvYUmi0Mqoo99XL/qu4CFMArVT/0dJyxAPCWh2938nE@xCpu2WzYurhHWyQPArd8z8L98mlTBwMxsHZ5LZmdJh5Avd2ruV94lWPbjYNuwQ5kjBG7qL1@OHYr93ztm1gm0bEIMtZg@vmXTlkS0GiDfw0ZJKo1fXeploVqJ4gNUYKWT5RQuHwJlKi1Y9i@QU)

-3 after spotting the updated clarification "the input will only have one ? and it will always be the last character."

-1 with thanks to @ChasBrown

Basically a port of my [Lotus Notes answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/192913/56555). Curiously, the clarification noted above does not help the Notes answer because `@Ends` is 4 bytes  cheaper than `@Contains`. Now if only there was an `@In` function...

Comment: [Save 1 byte](https://tio.run/##TY8/b4MwEMX3fopXT0a4kdIRKUXdMkVZq7SDGww5gX3ENmr49PSgS294@vndnyePc75xeF3aw@cyWP/dWFCl1YdLymh1YmXoQrvYUmi0Mqoo99XL/qu4CFMArVT/0dJyxAPCWh2938nE@xCpu2WzYurhHWyQPArd8z8L98mlTBwMxsHZ5LZmdJh5Avd2ruV94lWPbjYNuwQ5kjBG7qL1@OHYr93ztm1gm0bEIMtZg@vmXTlkS0GiDfw0ZJKo1fXeploVqJ4gNUYKWT5RQuHwJlKi1Y9i@QU) by using `rfind`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 23 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ø'? ?Uq, hoinu¹Ìk'?:`Y
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=%2bCc/ID9VcSwgaG9pbnW5zGsnPzpgWYM&input=IkhtbS4i)

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>120</s> 118 bytes

Function-like macro:

```cpp
#include<string>
#define f(s)({int i{},j{};for(;s[i];)j=s[++i]-44?j:i;s[--i]-63?"Yes":j?std::string(s-~j,i+~j):"No";})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZJPb5wwEMXvfIqJc4Gu6aVRD/zJKrdIlZJeq@0qsmDYNYttYhu1aEW@@nYwUVLR9IJ4v3nzPB6o@j49VNXlWqreWF9I47xFoW6J6KobaiwISH24ja5rbKRGaGKXxGepPcjzxNvzlDfGxrnbyX2etKXbbTZyn97cbNtMEk1TUl@/bNkPdCxrt87XWbZkxi59abncvLRJxh4My6fkMud6dD6ujsJ@krofPK@Mdh4CwN89Vh7rJzN4KiXnCMTgDVh0Q@fLJg4dSR6BbOJXWK6bIoAwRUW6KNju8dv@p2bUg53DVbGJWVGEUBIJlEByySUNV0Gv8qkQ4qZICanjtxlHdGXYQv4KtCnDtaPlxuxeqc@Mky15Q3edlYej52vsTqAQhB79kRZ59Z8yPA@kpdEc@g6Fw3@MFmE0A5iTGLeMa/NeejArcI8jrw06oCMd9NYcrFDwy9gTGdnHFfbe/khHcHBmMQX77IC5@QP8V@f3MDoHUdf04IFyqAKjX8PTkmkHHBR9FEn3nKlSwoXk5XVOmy5/AA)

-2 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 72 bytes

```cs
x=>x.Last()!=63?"Yes":x.Contains(',')?x.Split(',').Last().Trim('?'):"No"
```

Saved 2 bytes thanks to @someone

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZFBS8QwEIXv@ytmc2mLsRfBw65NEUH2sKyCggh7CW22G7ZJaibV9tfXNBEteMnw3ny8GSYVXlcop8deV3forNQNjYWdimko2JDvObo0Wxe3NyV5F0g2Q/5gtONSY5rQJCuH/KVrpQvih85frVRpUibZhhwMmbarTyNrcMI3YzxI3fUug4LBm5VO7KUWKWGMAYGr2PSVHHU0Tmnks@0qhJCdUjn5Vfetlc3Z0YWDF1ACuB7d2Y9b/@/AR@@1NJpC1wqOYslYAaPpwVz4WP7ZB7MQOzHS2ggEPwChs6axXMGXsZcF9OQDKKCJUMBnAhbIcxhOgde1f2g4EoUqeFU89PwroPrWSb/p7CrFcY6YvgE)

Comment: `SkipLast(1) -> Trim('?')` for -??? bytes as far as I see (all my attempts to calculate the difference result in different numbers)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 bytes

```
Ṗṣ”,Ṫ⁾NoḊ?Ɗ“Yes”i?”?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzmkPdy5@1DBX5@HOVY8a9/nlP9zRZX@s61HDnMjUYqB4pj2QsP///7@OPQA)